# testing for command line args in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I am testing to see if the first argument to my script is `--foo`

```
if [ $# > 1 ]
then
    if [[ "$1" = "--foo" ]]
    then
        echo "foo is set"
        foo = 1
    fi
fi

if [[ -n "$foo"]]
then
    #dosomething
fi
```

Can someone pleaset tell me what is the bash way of testing if `--foo` is present as one of the arguments, not necessarily the first one?

Comment: @Prospero: broken link

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should use the external `getopt` utility if you want to support long options. If you only need to support short options, it's better to use the the Bash builtin `getopts`.

Here is an example of using `getopts` (`getopt` is not too much different):

```
options=':q:nd:h'
while getopts $options option
do
    case $option in
        q  )    queue=$OPTARG;;
        n  )    execute=$FALSE; ret=$DRYRUN;; # do dry run
        d  )    setdate=$OPTARG; echo "Not yet implemented.";;
        h  )    error $EXIT $DRYRUN;;
        \? )    if (( (err & ERROPTS) != ERROPTS ))
                then
                    error $NOEXIT $ERROPTS "Unknown option."
                fi;;
        *  )    error $NOEXIT $ERROARG "Missing option argument.";;
    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

Not that your first test will always show a `true` result and will create a file called "1" in the current directory. You should use (in order of preference):

```
if (( $# > 1 ))
```

or

```
if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
```

or

```
if [ $# -gt 1 ]
```

Also, for an assignment, you can't have spaces around the equal sign:

```
foo=1
```

Comment: Thanks, I switched to using getopts. I see that I cannot learn bash by googling around randomly, lots of gotchas, will have to be more systematic :)

Comment: @MK: There are lots of good questions and answers related to Bash on SO, plus several that include pointers to good places to learn more.

Answer (score 12):

As Dennis noted, `getopt` and `getopts` are the standard ways for parsing command line arguments.  For an alternative way, you could use the *$@* special variable, which expands to **all** of the command line arguments.  So, you could test for it using the **wildcard** in your test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $@ == *foo* ]]
then
    echo "You found foo"
fi
```

That said, you'll be better off if you figure out getopt sooner rather than later.

Comment: There's no need to double the asterisks. This technique can be used as a quick test, but it's prone to false positives.

Comment: Right -- definitely prone to false positives.  And I never can remember where the double asterisks are used; my memory failed me here.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind regarding double asterisks is for Bash 4 with `shopt -s globstar`, zsh and ksh93 for doing recursive globbing.

Comment: I think you should edit your answer to take out the double asterisks, This way is very handy for adding a --help or --version to your script [[ $@ == <asterisk>--help<asterisk> ]]